# Not able to view fieldLabel of my hbox layout panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a panel and the layout is hbox,I have two textfileds as items of the panel.

I am not able to view the fieldLabels  when i execute .Please find the code

```
         Ext.onReady(function(){
        var panel = new Ext.Panel({
           title:"HBox Panel",
           layout:'hbox',
           width:300,
           height:200,
           renderTo:document.body,
           items:[
                    {
                     xtype:"textfield",
                     fieldLabel:"Label1"
                    },
                    {
                     xtype:"textfield",
                     fieldLabel:"Label2"
                    }

                 ]


           });
        });
```

Note:I am working on Ext 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, the `fieldLabel` option will only apply in a form layout context (usually provided by the form panel).

As a quick fix, you can display your labels in [`BoxComponent`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.BoxComponent):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var panel = new Ext.FormPanel({
        title: "HBox Panel",
        layout: 'hbox',
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        renderTo: document.body,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'box'
            ,html: '<label class="x-form-item-label" style="width: auto; margin: 0 5px;">'
                + 'Label 1:</label>'
            ,cls: 'x-form-item'
        },{
            xtype: "textfield"
        },{
            xtype: 'box'
            ,html: '<label class="x-form-item-label" style="width: auto; margin: 0 5px;">'
                + 'Label 2:</label>'
            ,cls: 'x-form-item'
        },{
            xtype: "textfield"
        }]
    });
});
```

Of course, it would be cleaner to create a CSS class for the custom styles, or even extend a new component from `BoxComponent`.

You can also generalize this logic in the parent panel's `initComponent` method, to create box components for the labels from the configured `fieldLabel` of the field (this way you could also set the `for` attribute of the `label` tag because you'll know the generated `id` of the field components at this time).

Answer (score 2):

Your layout should be `form`. From the [api documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-fieldLabel):

> **fieldLabel** config is only used when this Component is rendered by a
>   Container which has been configured to use the FormLayout layout
>   manager (e.g. [Ext.form.FormPanel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.FormPanel) or specifying layout:'form').

Answer (score 0):

change the layout type to form,

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
       title:"HBox Panel",
       layout:'form',
       width:300,
       height:200,
       renderTo:document.body,
       items:[
                {
                 xtype:"textfield",
                 fieldLabel:"Label1"
                },
                {
                 xtype:"textfield",
                 fieldLabel:"Label2"
                }

             ]


       });
    });
```